# How to ask for camera resource without actually turning the camera on?

Tags: javascript, html, camera

I know that running

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMeida({video: true})
```

will prompt my website to ask for user camera.

But if I run this, and user agrees, it will immediately turn on the camera.

Since I don't need camera right away, i want to turn it off immediately.

But turning them off takes about ~ 30 seconds.

Is there a way to prompt user for camera permission, without actually using it?

This is so that when I actually use the camera, i don't need to deal with any of those permission stuff.

Is this possible?

Comment: Whats wrong with spying the user? I mean if he agreed to allow access to his camera, whats wrong with simply let it be switched on?

Comment: @Jonasw Not much wrong, but on a mac the camera light is on and it annoys me lol. Also i am asking permission on page load, so i don't want my website to have it on all the time.